# Outlook for Mac "Your database could not be rebuilt [-47]"

Tags: ms-office, database

Recently, whenever I open Outlook, it tells me that my the database needs to be rebuilt.  I attempted to and received an error the first time.  I deleted the database file located in `Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/` and attempted to run the rebuild again, and it failed with an error code -47.

I restarted the computer and still no luck.  Any ideas of how I can rebuild the database and not lose my identity?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you delete the database ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 because it was corrupted, so deleting the database file saves a step for Microsoft Database Utility to create a new database file.

Comment: Interesting action !?

Comment: How can you rebuild something that is not longer there. Are you trying to make new identity?

Comment: @Buscar웃 The database file is not the bread and butter, so if it's not there the utility creates a new one based on the identity, but if you don't understand how Outlook database files are created, I suggest you do some research. I'm not trying to make a new identity, I want to save the content in the existing identity.